# Why aren't all my categorical variables included in the OLS model from statsmodels?

Tags: regression, statsmodels

I'm using `statsmodels` to perform an Ordinary Least Squares regression between two categorical variables and a continuous dependent variable.

My data is structured like this:

```
Group    Model    Rate 
----------------------
Group A  Model 1  1.3
Group B  Model 7  0.43
Group B  Model 1  0.77
Group G  Model 2  3.2
```

I'm trying to correlate the group and machine variables with the rate outcome.

I've used `statsmodels.formula.api.ols` to create the model, but after fitting it, the result doesn't seem to contain all values of my categorical variables.

This is how I created and fit the model:

```py
model = statsmodels.formula.api.ols('rates ~ C(models) + C(groups)', data=df)
fitted_model = model.fit()
```

The result looks good and makes sense, except the missing values. I inspected the result by looking at the `fitted_model.params`. It lists all levels of my "Group" variable but one, and same for the "Model". It also gives an "Intercept".

I'm guessing my issue is statistical, rather than coding. Is there a reason one level of each categorical variable would be elided? If I'm interested in the effect of those missing levels on my outcome (coefficients, p-values), how can I find that out?

Comment: It's coding: search our site for "dummy" (an unfortunate name for these variables!) or "categorical" with "coding" for explanations.

Comment: @whuber Right, right, I do know about encoding categorical variables, but it's been a while since I read about it. So that's why one value is being omitted, but then how could I calculate some number for its correlation or p-value?

Comment: That's a matter of telling your software either to use a different coding or following up with explicit testing, which again is a software issue.