# How to calculate statistics for categorical variable level omitted by one-hot encoding?

Tags: regression, statsmodels

I'm performing an ordinary least squares regression on a dataset whose predictors are two categorical variables and the dependent variable is continuous.

The resulting model gives me stats like the coefficient and p-value for each value (level) of the categorical variables, except one value is omitted for each variable. After some helpful pointers on my [last question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488527/why-arent-all-my-categorical-variables-included-in-the-ols-model-from-statsmode), I now realize that's because of the one-hot encoding, and why.

This [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342739/difference-between-dummy-variable-categories-that-werent-omitted/343498#343498) gives some useful tips on calculating the coefficients of the missing predictors, but I also need the p-values as well.

### Details

I'm using `statsmodels` in Python, so it'd be great if there was a way to do it using that. Here's how I created and fit the model:

```py
model = statsmodels.formula.api.ols('rates ~ C(models) + C(groups)', data=df)
fitted_model = model.fit()
```

And here's how my data is structured:

```
Group    Model    Rate 
----------------------
Group A  Model 1  1.3
Group B  Model 7  0.43
Group B  Model 1  0.77
Group G  Model 2  3.2
```

Comment: You need the p-value of what hypothesis test?

Comment: ... and once you can tell us that, you may discover this is the same as [your first question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488527).

Comment: @Dave So I'm using the p-values provided by `statsmodels`, and my understanding is that's a measure of whether that particular predictor is significantly correlated with the dependent variable. The library's definition is "The two-tailed p values for the t-stats of the params."

Comment: What hypothesis do you want to test?

Comment: @Dave I think my null hypothesis is that this particular value of this categorical variable is not predictive of the outcome variable. At least, that's my understanding of the other p-values that `statsmodels` does give.